# MDS DBAListRowLimit don't affect max number of items in drop down list in Excel add in

Tags: sql-server, excel, master-data-services, mds

First time I changed DBAListRowLimit in mdm.tblSystemSetting from 50 to 10000 it affects in Excel addin. So I see the drop down list with number of items more than 50 and less then 10000. After that I changed it back, but MDS Excel addin didn't reflect it - it is still showing drop down lists with a total items numbers more than 50.

Does anybody know how can I get it back or switch to default MDS settings?

I tried:

- To restart Excel
- To restart IIS with MDS
- To Change DBAListRowLimit throw UI (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Master Data Services\Configuration\MDSConfigTool.exe).
- To add a new attribute (as a domain based) - it's also shown as a drop down list (with much more than 50 items)
- To create new app server (on IIS) to the same MDS db

nothing helps.

- MS SQL Server 2014, version 12.0.2456.0
- MS Excel 2016, version 16.0.4266.1001
- MDS Excel add-in URL: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=309620

Thank you!

Comment: Can you be more consistent about what are you exactly asking? Because from what I understand, what you want is to restore default MDS settings. If this is right, you could rephrase it much clear

Comment: Andrew, thanks! I want to restore MDS Excel Add-in behaviour around the drop down lists. Restoring all MDS defaults is the last resort. The main problem is that Excel now doesn't accept dictionary values, entered by name only. I think this problem relate to the DBAListRowLimit change.